# how to initialize from the JSON IN SWIFT

Tags: ios, json

I have an api ex:-

```
{data:[{name:a,location:{city:h}},{}],a:{},b:{}}
```

this is pattern .I am developing this `mvvm` method.

So i created a model for this

in that i given as :-

```
var city:string!

var name:string!
```

i need to  get the values from this  .

ex:

```
init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

            guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
                let description = dictionary["description"] as? String else {
                    return
            }

            self.name = name
            self.description = description
        }
```

in below is an example. so how to get the valuest in the model using swift

sample example:-  hostelmodel

```
class hostelmodel{



        var name :String!
        var description :String!

        init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

            guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
                let description = dictionary["description"] as? String else {
                    return
            }

            self.name = name
            self.description = description
        }



}
```

in hotelviewmodel:-

```
 class hostelviewmodel:NSObject{


        var datasourceModel:DataSourceModel

        init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel:DataSourceModel) {
            datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
        }


        func datafordisplay(atindex index: Int) -> hostelmodel {
          return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![index]

        }

    }
```

in DataSourceModel:-

```
class DataSourceModel: NSObject {

    var dataListArray:Array<hostelmodel>? = []


    init?(array :Array<[String:Any]>) {

        var datalist:Array<hostelmodel> = []
        for dict in array{

            let model = hostelmodel(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist        
}
}
```

in hostelview:-

```
 private var HOSTELMODEL :hostelmodel!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withViewModel viewModel:hostelviewmodel) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        HOSTELMODEL = viewModel
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

i don't know what should give in tableview datasource..here...

And finally the webservice class:-

private var url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

```
class WebService{

    func loadFlowers(completion :@escaping ([hostelmoddel]) -> ()) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

            if let data = data {

                let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                let dictionaries = json as! [JSONDictionary]

                let model = DataSourceModel(array: <#T##Array<[String : Any]>#>)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(dictionaries.flatMap(hostelmodel.init))
                }

            }

            }.resume()

    }





}
```

This code is not fully completed .So this is the pattern .So how to do to get the values and to display the values in tableview .It must in mvvm method and it should not use the storyboard.How to do .

Answer (score 0):

If you can iterate over the values in the "data" array then the class structure that you're looking for is something like this:

```
    class ModelName {
        var name: String?
        var city: String?

        init(_ dictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
            if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String, let location = dictionary["location"] as? [String: Any], let city = location["city"] as? String {
                self.name = name
                self.city = city
            }
        }
    }

    class BusinesLogic {
        var dataList: [ModelName]?

        func getList() -> [ModelName]? {
            return dataList
        }

        func initializeData(_ rawDataArray: [[String : Any]]) {
            rawDataArray.forEach { rawData in
                dataList?.append(ModelName.init(rawData))
            }
        }
    }

// so to use:

    let sample = BusinesLogic()
    sample.initializeData([DATA ARRAY HERE])
    sample.getList()
```

Comment: what means here Dictionary<string,Any>)   can u explain ,i don't understand why it given as .

Comment: That's the Dictionary Type in swift

Comment: i am doing in mvvm method .so did i need to create a datasourcemodel for this.if so how to do.ex: var dataListArray:Array<hostelModel>? = []
    
    
    init?(array :Array<[String:Any]>) {
        
        var datalist:Array<hostelModel> = []
        for dict in array{
            
            let model = hostelModel(dictionary: dict)
            
            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }
}

Comment: Not sure what exactly how you want it implemented but I did some edit to the class. Check out my answer again. Hope it helps

Comment: i have edited my question .How to do according to that problem.how to solve this